# Errors with DeepLearnToolBox in Matlab R2012a

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, octave

I am trying to use this toolbox in matlab, however i'm having some problems when i run the test functions due to octave specific code that is present. eg:

https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox/blob/master/DBN/dbnsetup.m

Has # based comments which I am getting errors about, and more seriously in:

https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox/blob/master/DBN/rbmtrain.m

Where there is multiple instances of octave based code such as ++ and do while statements.

Am I doing something wrong to get this running?

I would prefer to use Matlab as opposed to octave, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was an incorrect pull request. The author has fixed this, and the master branch is now working.

Answer (score 1):

As a start, you need to replace the `#` by `%` in the comments, and rewrite the lines using `++` and `do while` using valid MATLAB syntax.